# Список месяцев в обратном порядке

Tags: php, дата

День добрый. Для вывода статистики надо получить список последних 6 и 12 месяцев от текущего включительно. Пробовал:

```
for($i = 11;$i > -1;$i--){
    $m = $i*30;
    $index = date('Ym',strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime("today")));
}
```

Но так как в месяцах не всегда 30 дней то в последних числах месяца список будет неточный. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
for($i = 11, $time = time(); $i > -1; $i--, $time -= date('t', $time) * 86400){
    $index = date('Ym', $time);
}
```